# Could not resolve com.commonsware.cwac:saferoom.x:1.0.0

Tags: android, android-room, commonsware-cwac, commonsware

```
     Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:crewforceReleaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.commonsware.cwac:saferoom.x:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.commonsware.cwac:saferoom.x:1.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'http://trovmbuildagt1:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/commonsware/cwac/saferoom.x/1.0.0/saferoom.x-1.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'http://trovmbuildagt1:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/commonsware/cwac/saferoom.x/1.0.0/saferoom.x-1.0.0.pom'.
               > Connect to trovmbuildagt1:8081 [trovmbuildagt1/208.64.239.185] failed: Connection timed out: no further information
      > Could not resolve com.commonsware.cwac:saferoom.x:1.0.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/com/commonsware/cwac/saferoom.x/1.0.0/saferoom.x-1.0.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/com/commonsware/cwac/saferoom.x/1.0.0/saferoom.x-1.0.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

I am getting this error while building the app , any fix for this?

Comment: Note that CWAC-SafeRoom is discontinued. SQLCipher for Android supports Room directly -- you no longer need CWAC-SafeRoom.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , we will be migrating soon.

Comment: Any idea of a migration plan that can still keep the old DB? 
Just replacing SafeRoom with SQLCipher breaks the access to the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
maven {
    url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
}
```

in your project level gradle file like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And try other versions like `1.1.2` or `1.1.1`

```
implementation 'com.commonsware.cwac:saferoom.x:1.1.2'
```

because looks like the `1.0.0` is not available.

Reference  -  https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-saferoom/blob/master/README-original.markdown#installation

Comment: Thanks a ton my issue was not adding maven url in all projects repositories instead I was adding this in app level repositories .